# Cannot install YUM on WSL

Tags: apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux, yum

I am trying to install yum to install another app on my WSL but keep getting the error cannot find the package.  I am using the following command:

```
sudo apt install -y yum
```

It is returning this:

> Reading package lists... Done

> Building dependency tree

> Reading state information... Done

> E: Unable to locate package yum

Search the net I keep seeing to update the apt so I am using this:

```
 sudo apt update
```

Returns the following:

> Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114
> kB]
>
> Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
>
> Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114
> kB]
>
> Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101
> kB]
>
> Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64
> Packages [1129 kB]
>
> Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64
> Packages [843 kB]
>
> Fetched 2300 kB in 6s (405 kB/s)

> Reading package lists... Done

> Building dependency tree

> Reading state information... Done

> All packages are up to date.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yum isn't available for Debian/Ubuntu. It's a wrong assumption that you need "yum to install another app" probably stemming from some tutorial/guide/instructions for RH based desktop Linux distros.

Comment: ok, that explains alot.  So then what is the recommended way to install an RPM?

Comment: The recommended way is NOT INSTALL RPMs as they weren't package for Debian/Ubuntu. You need DEB, not RPM so try to find the software you want properly packaged for Debian derivatives. This is an X-Y problem.

Comment: Agreed, better to rephrase the question "How do I install (whatever app you were trying to install via yum) on WSL Ubuntu?"  But first search for *<that_app_name> ubuntu 20.04* or *<that_app_name> focal*, and you are almost certain to find instructions.  First give the "normal" Ubuntu directions a try -- They almost always work on WSL.  If you still have problems, let us know what you run into (in a new question).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu) Also consult about actual package names with https://packages.ubuntu.com/ . RPM on Debian are aliens.